# Isolate a matched virtual column ruler to the cursorline only?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, cursorline, ruler

I'd like to add ruler marks/virtual columns along the lines of

`matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v', 100)`

while *restricting their display to the cursorline*.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following two commands:

```
" Match when cursor before column
matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%#.*\zs\%81v', 100)

" Match when cursor after column
matchadd('ColorColumn', '\%81v\ze.*\%#', 100)
```

It should be possible to combine these into a single regular expression, but simply placing them into an alternation with `\|` doesn't work correctly*, so doing so seems like more trouble than it's worth.

These work by finding the cursor position `\%#` either following or followed by the specified column, but excluding everything apart from the column from the match with `\zs` and `\ze`.

See:

- `:help /\%#`
- `:help /\zs`
- `:help /\ze`

<sub>* At a guess, there may be some complexity in the interaction between `\zs`/`\ze` and alternation that I'm unaware of—you might have better luck with lookahead `\@=` and lookbehind `\@<=`, but note that these are inefficient compared to `\zs`/`\ze`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks so much Rich for code that works now and for the entrance to understanding and perhaps expanding on it.

Comment: I think this idea+impl has a lot of appeal for intra-line navigation:

o set marks every 20-30 chars, so there's not more than 3-4 on a line.  3-4 is small enough of a number to make it easy to infer the col number for each mark

o to go to a particular word, see the closest mark, and `l` to the col # that you infer for the mark, there you're likely close enough to get to the begin/end of a word/WORD via one of `[w,W,b,B] etc, maybe w/ a count, likely at most 2

Comment: o marks are on current line only, so you don't have a screen of colored column clutter.

o less complicated than most other solutions, from both code and operational pov, e.g. no new maps needed

Comment: @cesces Interesting idea. I generally just use `[count]f` or  `f;;;` for that sort of movement, though.